# Find items from a list which exist in another list

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

I have a `List<PropA>`

```
PropA  
{  
    int a;  
    int b;  
}
```

and another `List<PropX>`

```
PropX  
{  
    int a;  
    int b;  
}
```

Now i have to find items from `List<PropX>` which exist in `List<PropA>` matching **b** property using lambda or LINQ.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? This question has been answered way too many times already...

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe

Comment: @David Perhaps they each have different fields that he hasn't shown, or they have a different set of methods even though they have the same values, or any number of other reasons.

Comment: got it! I thought both a & b should match. It is my mistake.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want to do is `Join` the two sequences.  LINQ has a `Join` operator that does exactly that:

```
List<PropX> first;
List<PropA> second;

var query = from firstItem in first
    join secondItem in second
    on firstItem.b equals secondItem.b
    select firstItem;
```

Note that the `Join` operator in LINQ is also written to perform this operation quite a bit more efficiently than the naive implementations that would do a linear search through the second collection for each item.

Comment: There is also the other way of writing this... `first.Join(second, f => f.b, s => s.b, (fir, sec) => fir);`

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare Yes, and both are completely identical.  This will compile into that.  I've found that most people prefer `Join` to be written out using query syntax over method syntax, even more so than any of the other query methods.

Comment: Depending on how the business logic and input data goes, one may want to include a Distinct() call to remove duplicate values returned by the join.

Answer (score 91):

```
ListA.Where(a => ListX.Any(x => x.b == a.b))
```

Comment: Well, I ran a simple test and the results of a `Join` were *substantially* faster. http://ideone.com/xW1CnL .  You'll need to run the code yourself to use a larger data set.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to run the query. It seems that for a small enough data set (less than 500 items), the instantiation cost of join outweighs the performance gain.

Comment: If performance is out of the question, then I would take code simplicity. This would be a subjective and personal preference.

Comment: And in this case the operation being performed is fundamentally a join.  That is the semantic meaning of this code, so it makes the most sense to use that exact operator rather than using `Where` to implement your own `Join`.  `Join` does a *better* job of conveying the meaning to the reader as a result.

Answer (score 32):

```
var commonNumbers = first.Intersect(second);
```

This will give you the common values between two lists, a much faster and cleaner approach than join or other Lambda expressions.

Just try it.

Source : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This would only work if `T` was the same type for both `IEnumerable<T>` collections, which is not the case in the question asked.

Comment: +1, This is one of those cases where you open the question based on the **title** and this is the perfect answer to that part although it doesn't answer the actual **content** of the question.

Answer (score 7):

Well all above will not work if you have multiple parameters, So I think this is the best way to do it.

For example: Find not matched items from pets and pets2 .

```
var notMatchedpets = pets
    .Where(p2 => !pets2
    .Any(p1 => p1.Name == p2.Name && p1.age == p2.age))
    .ToList();
```