# How to set flag in one list for the Id's which match with the Id's in another list using Lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have two lists classes

```
public class class1{
 public Int Id { get; set; }
 public Bool Flag{ get; set; }
}

public class class2{
 public Int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have `List<class1>` and `List<class2>`,
Now i have to update Flag property to true in `List<class1>` for only those Ids which match with the Id's present in `List<class2>` using lambda expression c#.Don't want to use foreach.

Comment: Why don't you update `Flag` using regular `foreach`? Why lambda expression is a requirement?

Comment: So what exactly are you having problems with? Can you create a list of A? Can you create a list of B? Can you iterate though a list?

Comment: Anyway: why do you have to use a lambda? Did you try it using a classic loop before? Because when you can do the one you can also the other.

Comment: Without wanting to repeat the comments above: usually when people say _"I wanna use Linq/lambdas and not foreach"_ they are misguided about what you can do with Linq and expressions. Why don't you want to use foreach, even when that is probably the most readable and logical option?

Answer (score 1):

> using lambda expression. Don't want to use foreach.

That's usually a silly requirement and a hallmark that you're not really familiar with C#, Linq or performance analysis. You have a collection whose elements you want to modify, so you should use `foreach()`.

If you're trying out functional programming, then you should treat the list elements as immutable and project into a new collection.

The first part of your problem, looking up which list elements to modify based on a presence of one of their properties in another collection's elements' properties, [is trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769673/find-items-from-a-list-which-exist-in-another-list):

```
var elementsToModify = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id));
```

Now with a `foreach()`, this'll be simple:

```
foreach (var l1 in elementsToModify)
{
    l1.Flag = true;
}
```

Or, even denser (not that less code equals more performance):

```
foreach (var l1 in list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id)))
{
    l1.Flag = true;
}
```

So, there's your code. But you didn't want to use `foreach()`. Then you need to project into a new collection:

```
var newList1 = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id))
                    .Select(l1 => new Class1 
                    {
                        Id = l1.Id,
                        Flag = true,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

There you have it, a `List<Class1>` with only flagged items. Optionally you could use this list in a `foreach()` to update the original `list1`. Oh, wait.

Comment: Much better answer, upvote for the `any`, It must be time for me to clock off for the day

Comment: Your `Select()` approach also has something to say for it, but you're using both `foreach()` and `ForEach()`, so... :P

Answer (score 0):

The below solution does not use the classical "for each", but is compiled to one under the hood. If that's not what you meant, then please explain what you are trying to achieve. Using for each in this example is a good approach. One could also use `while` or `for` loops, but is it really what's being asked here?

Object definition:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```

List initialization:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>()
{
    new MyObject() { Id= 1 },
    new MyObject() { Id= 2 },
    new MyObject() { Id= 3 },
    new MyObject() { Id= 4 }
};

var list2 = new List<MyObject>()
{
    new MyObject() { Id= 2 },
    new MyObject() { Id= 4 }
};
```

Code:

```
list.ForEach(el => el.Flag = list2.Any(el2 => el2.Id == el.Id));
```

**EDIT:**

An example with a while loop (a bit nasty to do it this way):

```
int i = -1;
int numberOfElements = list.Count;
while (++i < numberOfElements)
{
    list[i].Flag = list2.Any(el => el.Id == list[i].Id);
}
```

I guess you can write a for loop yourself...